# Porting/cross-compiling external libs

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

How do you cross-compile libraries like SVL (Simple Vector Lib) or SDL_gfx for Linux/ARM CPU  when you're on Win 64? I'm using `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` to compile my stuff, but I have no idea how to do it with external libraries. I spent last 7 days googling, but no luck so far.

Comment: Do the external libraries have configure scripts?  Are you using GCC for your own compilation, or some other compiler?  There are ways of specifying cross-compilation with configure scripts (though I've never done it).

Comment: @Jonathan SVL is here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ajw/public/dist/svl-1.5.tar.gz it has some makefiles but no configs. Yes, I'm using GCC to compile my programs.

Comment: SVL is interesting; it is old (2002) and has a non-standard means of configuration (as you say, no ./configure). You run 'make' to find out the supported platforms (it doesn't list ARM); you run 'make OSX' for MacOS X (fortunately, it is not Pyramid OSX), and  then 'make' again. It didn't actually compile on MacOS X 10.6.4; problems with an overload of 'abs()'. So, you would have to devise a set of rules for ARM, and put them in makefiles/config-ARM.mf, and the rules would ensure that the C++ compiler is invoked with the correct cross-compilation flags. And then take it from there. Good luck!